# Cox regression python

Tags: python, cox-regression

Are there any packages in Python for survival analysis? Specifically, I am interested in performing a Cox regression?

I know this [example](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/survival-analysis-r-vs-python/#Loading-data-into-python-and-R) but it's in R. Could we just interface Python with R (using, for example, [rpy2](https://pypi.org/project/rpy2/))?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know this rule

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lifelines package in Python offers survival analysis, including the Cox proportional hazard fitter: https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 7):

I would just like to provide a more updated answer as of July 2020:

- Like [ilse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5909832/ilse) mentioned, [lifelines](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a great package for all things survival analysis. It plays very nicely with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and has some great [visualization tools](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html) out of the box. It is being constantly developed and updated. Moreover, its documentation is very thorough. I would even recommend reading it as a starting point for studying survival analysis in general.
- [scikit-surv](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is another option. While it lacks some of lifelines's features, its strong suit is that it is based on [`scikit-learn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/), which makes it very easy to couple with other building blocks in your pipeline. Moreover, it includes implementations of ML algorithms for survival, such as [Random Survival Forests](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/sksurv.ensemble.RandomSurvivalForest.html?highlight=random%20fores) and [SSVMs](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/sksurv.svm.FastKernelSurvivalSVM.html?highlight=support%20vector).
- Lastly, we have [PySurvival](https://square.github.io/pysurvival/). I have no experience with this framework, but it looks like it has quite a few algorithms as well. It is built on top [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/), among others.

Answer (score 4):

One more library to add to @arturo's list:

- [PyCox](https://github.com/havakv/pycox): built on top of PyTorch, and provides a handful of modern deep-learning based algorithms for survival prediction.